# Interface property not enforcing both getter and setter when implemented on a class

Tags: typescript

```
interface IMyInterface {
  property1: string;
}

class MyClassWithSetterOnly implements IMyInterface { // <--- Expect error, because property1 is missing a getter
  private _property1: string = 'default';
  set property1(v: string) {
    this._property1 = v;
  }
}

class MyClassWithGetterOnly implements IMyInterface { // <--- Expect error, because property1 is missing a setter
  private _property1: string = 'default';
  get property1(): string {
    return this._property1;
  }
}

const setterOnly = new MyClassWithSetterOnly();
const getterOnly = new MyClassWithGetterOnly();

setterOnly.property1 = 'value';
getterOnly.property1 = 'value'; // <--- Error as expected, because property1 is missing a setter

console.log(setterOnly.property1); // <--- Expect error, because property1 is missing a getter
console.log(getterOnly.property1);
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFkCerzXk5AbwFgAoZZABygHtLoxMBGALmQGcwpQBzAbjIBfMmQQAbOO3bIsAYQlSA6sDAALAMoQwkKAHkQYzMmABbSmIgmI4aRmy5YiFIWQB6V8gA8AWl-IAogAe9AhgyNC0UAA0yABGEAhwAK7sKNR0DMzG0ibAUrzIcMg8WjpkFNTAAG5wkMgA+un0UIysHFwFALzIAOQAJhDwSWJgPQLkHFpUtM2tABRVbJzcIDwAlETlFMhqeQB0jTOZTMjdVeMUwqRXogrScnfKagDipdD6hsZmFlY2aFg4HT4ZxuDw+PxBEJhCI0aJxBLJVLTDItLJ5ZC5fKrQqTbTQLaVGp1Q4o1pLDrY7r9QbJEZjLYlMJNY5zNbklY8TYTChQLRJKAgHaqfYk2bMC7IK43UgIGggTi4nQfIzdEAQADuMkw8kk7CeGjeegMmFZ41l8rCjKVxtOyDVmoeuv1rzxRsMppEpFSruVe2ZqJOVJqYiSEHppCt72NfqOAdtPWDobGoK8vm8ASgkUK0ggwQSkD6MXiiRSaVjrWyGLy7AKRW9ZVIojl7BoFj2YhoPDm9ajhhjpOYaz4KfB6ch+fCmdhRYRpeRYpO6MxNexRUjUCb8tbEHbnbm699-taQ7IQA)

This seems like clear type checking bug in TypeScript (4.4.0-beta and below), though I'm having trouble finding the specific issues related to both the interface enforcing and the fact that there's no error when trying to access a property where there is not getter.

Comment: This is probably not a good question for SO. I would suggest opening an issue in the repository; just note that you tried to find similar/duplicate issues but were unsuccessful. Maybe it wasn't even reported yet. In any case, the maintainers might be able to quickly point to a duplicate and if none exist then all the better that an issue has been opened.

Comment: Thanks, I started to have that feeling as I wrote this. Will do.

Comment: Oh, well, I got here too late to prevent that issue from being opened.  See [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45517#issuecomment-902139448) for my thoughts about existing relevant GitHub issues and what's going on there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to answer this with the TypeScript issue I opened in the hope that others find it useful:

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45517